# RoR: Highcharts boost.js not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, boost, highcharts

I've several graphs with an huge amount of data, which is pretty slow. So I decided to use Highcharts own solution: boost.js.

My application.js file loads all additional JS-files, inclusive the boost.js. I've read that the boost-file needs to be loaded after the Highcharts file itself.

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require ./vendor/highcharts
//= require ./vendor/boost
//= require ./vendor/moment
//= require_tree ./vendor/
//= require_tree ./source/
```

Then I've precompiled the whole assets:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

After that I restarted the server. But unfortunately it's not possible to load the boost-file. 
Error-Message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/boost.js.map"):
```

Following versions are included:

- Rails: 5.2.4.1
- Highcharts: 8.0
- Ruby: 2.5.1

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @raestro, How have you added the boost file? The path should be: `highcharts/modules/boost` if you get Highcharts from npm.

Comment: @ppotaczek: Yes it's added, but not with npm. It's just copied in the same folder where the highcharts file is.

Comment: Please try to copy also `boost.js.map` file.